# Append GCLID to url with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-ads-api

### Hello everyone

So, I have a problem with **Google AdWords**, and the transferring of the **GCLID**.

**A bit of info:**

I have a site that generates leads, and I need to be able to tell which lead is coming from my **AdWords** **ads**. I can track the number of conversions in **AdWords** and **Analytics** no problem, but I need to set the specific leads a part in my backend.

Does anyone know how I can get javascript to append something to the URL, whenever the system finds the **GCLID** cookie that is stored?

Maybe my explanation is a but fuzzy, but hope you get the idea :-)